# How to run a command from the GitHub directory that Jenkins clones into?

Tags: jenkins

I put "make" in Jenkins's Execute Shell, following the tutorial here https://github.com/jbankes/Hello_Jenkins, but Jenkins does not run the make from the underlying Github repository, as shown in the error message below.

What is the right way to demand Jenkins to run "make" from its monitored GitHub repository?

```
    Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace /var/jenkins_home/workspace/test003
The recommended git tool is: NONE
No credentials specified
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/zhoulaifu/Hello_Jenkins # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/zhoulaifu/Hello_Jenkins
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git --version # 'git version 2.20.1'
 > git fetch --tags --force --progress -- https://github.com/zhoulaifu/Hello_Jenkins +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision bc3931a313e4f3945c257ae3247e63265b1debb7 (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f bc3931a313e4f3945c257ae3247e63265b1debb7 # timeout=10
Commit message: "Otherside (#5)"
 > git rev-list --no-walk bc3931a313e4f3945c257ae3247e63265b1debb7 # timeout=10
[test003] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins2704537311990415428.sh
+ make
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Should you navigate to the `cd original/` folder after clone where make is located?

Comment: Thanks. How would I know the path for "original/" then? I mean, in this case, the hard path is /var/jenkins_home/workspace/test003/original, but is there a Jenkins's way to get it, e.g. from a env. variable?

Comment: Normally you should know your repository structure and probably will store `Make` file in the root directory. So your pipeline will work.

Answer (score 1):

In the [repository](https://github.com/jbankes/Hello_Jenkins) `Make` file located inside `original` folder. So to be able to run `Make` you need navigate to it.

After `git clone` execute `cd original/` and then run `Make`.